# startActivityForResult causes my app to freeze on some devices

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat, startactivityforresult, android-vpn-service

I have a device-specific problem.
My app starts an intent with `startActivityForResult`, this works with almost all test devices only on some Android 7 devices, this leads to an APP freeze, where the GUI doesn't react anymore.

The code looks like this:

```
private void executeAction() {

    if("connect".equals(mStringAction)){

        Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(MainActivity.this);

        if(intent != null){
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONNECT_VPN); // Leads to freeze on some devices like Bacon android 7.1.2 Lineage OS
        }else{
            onActivityResult(REQUEST_CONNECT_VPN, RESULT_OK, null);
        }
```

REQUEST_CONNECT_VPN is int with value 2

Unfortunately, `onActivityResult` is never reached. After calling within `startActivityForResult`, `super. startActivityForResult (intent, requestCode);` nothing happens after breakpoints in the app. Among all the other devices it jumps back to `onActivityResult`.

If the intent is null, the APP works properly (except for the skipped code part) and does not freeze.

So my question is why most devices call `onActivityResult` properly and why it leads to a freeze on several Android 7 devices on the other hand?

Edit:

I found out `startActivityForResult` caused the app to freeze on some devices, I now added `android:launchMode="standard">` to the Manifest. This fixed the freeze for some of the devices which would not work. But apparently there are a view more devices which will just receive `RESULT_CANCELED` every time.

Comment: how r u preparing intent with VpnService?

Comment: This is an android class from VpnService.java. The methods looks like this:
[VpnService Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#prepare(android.content.Context))